# System.IndexOutOfRangeException Error Message for arrays on Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am pretty new to Visual Basic. I am attempting to sort numbers from smallest to largest without having to use "Array.Sort" or "Array.Reverse". So instead I am trying to use the Bubble sort Algorithm. Unfortunately, I am running into a range index error and I do not know how to resolve this issue.

```
Dim temp As Decimal
Dim index1 As Decimal
Dim index2 As Decimal
Dim index3 As Decimal
Dim numbers = New Decimal() {7.3, 32.2, 4.8, 28.3, -6.8, 101.7, -67.9, 40.7, 6.9, 99.9}

temp = 0.0
index1 = 0
index2 = -67.9
index3 = 99.9

Do While index2 <= 99.9
    For index1 = 0 To index3 - 1

        If (numbers(index1) > numbers(index1 + 1)) Then
            temp = numbers(index1)
            numbers(index1) = numbers(index1 + 1)
            numbers(index1) = temp

        End If
    Next

    index1 = 0
    index2 = index2 + 1
    index3 = index3 - 1

Loop

Console.ReadLine()
```

I am expecting to display the current values, and the sorted values as well.

Comment: I think you're mixing up the index and the value in the position in the array. Your `For` loop should go from 0 to the count of items in the array.

Comment: You need to use non-negative integers for array indexes, not Decimal values. Perhaps fixing that issue will lead you to fixing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the bubble sort algorithm is incorrect.

Try this instead of the `Do While` loop:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
    For j As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - i - 2
        If numbers(j) > numbers(j + 1) Then
            temp = numbers(j)
            numbers(j) = numbers(j + 1)
            numbers(j + 1) = temp
        End If
    Next
Next
```

To display the sorted values:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 1
    Console.WriteLine(numbers(i))
Next
```

Also no need to declare `index1`, `index2` and `index3`.

Comment: Hello Phillipe, thank you for your suggestion. Would the j in the code be a placeholder for the index? Also, how would I be able to display the values from this Do While Loop? Sorry for all my questions.

Comment: Hi David, basically the j loops from i to the end of the array. I will edit the answer to show the display.

Comment: See [link](https://www.productplan.com/glossary/bubble-sort/#:~:text=Bubble%20sort%20is%20a%20basic,they%20are%20out%20of%20order.) for explanation of the algorithm

Comment: No problem David.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds like you want three arrays, one for the original order, one for ascending, and one for descending. How about this?

```
Dim numbers() = New Decimal() {7.3, 32.2, 4.8, 28.3, -6.8, 101.7, -67.9, 40.7, 6.9, 99.9}
Dim sorted() As Decimal, reversed() As Decimal
ReDim sorted(UBound(numbers))
ReDim reversed(UBound(numbers))
BubbleSort(numbers, sorted, reversed)

Private Sub BubbleSort(original() As Decimal, ascending() As Decimal, descending() As Decimal)
    Dim temp As Decimal, flag As Boolean = True, outerIndex As Integer, innerIndex As Integer
    Array.Copy(original, ascending, UBound(original))
    Array.Copy(original, descending, UBound(original))
    For outerIndex = UBound(ascending) - 1 To LBound(ascending) Step -1
        For innerIndex = LBound(ascending) To outerIndex
            temp = ascending(innerIndex + 1)
            If ascending(innerIndex) > temp Then
                flag = False
                ascending(innerIndex + 1) = ascending(innerIndex)
                ascending(innerIndex) = temp
            End If
        Next
        If flag Then Exit For
        flag = True
    Next
    ' Reverse the sort
    For outerIndex = LBound(ascending) To UBound(ascending)
        descending(UBound(descending) - outerIndex) = ascending(outerIndex)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that the arrays are passed in, and they are automatically passed by reference.

Note also that the outer loop has a short-circuit, in case the list gets prematurely sorted, so gets to exit early.